# If a set of differentiable functions S={$f1,…,fn$} with common domain $D=[a,b]$, is linearly independent, then so is S′={$f′1,f′2,…,f′n$}?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, linear-transformations, independence

I have a (maybe too simple) question: I have to prove if different sets of equations are or aren't linearly independent. The case which is making trouble is ${sinx, cosx, 1}$. I have found out about the Wronskian, so I guess this implies that if a colection of functions (i.e. ${sinx, cosx, 1}$) is linearly independent, then so will be its derivative? Is that approach right? My idea was to derivate twice, and then try to solve the equations system for $a, b, c$ to prove that $a=b=c=0$, and thus the three functions are linearly independent. Is this also right?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Linearly, not lineally.

Comment: You only have to tell a zero/nonzero Wrońskian.

Comment: Another method is to use standard methods to reduce $a \sin x + b\cos x$ to a single trigonometric function of the form $r\cos (x+s)$ with $r$ and $s$ constant.

Comment: What  do you mean by "a combination of functions is linearly independent"? One can only talk about independence of a *collection* of functions such as for example $$\{\sin x,\cos x, 1\}.$$ Independence would then mean that if $$a\sin x+b\cos x+ c=0$$ then necessarily $a=b=c=0$. Is that what you actually mean?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know the right name to describe it, I'm editing it.

Comment: I suggest you edit both the question and title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question you have is the following:

*If a set of differentiable functions  $S=\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ with common domain $D=[a,b]$, is linearly independent, then so is
$S'=\{f_1',f_2',\ldots,f_n'\}?$*

The answer is yes, provided no function in $S$ is the translation of another, ie you cannot have $x^2$ and $x^2+3$ in $S$ for example. Also, $S$ cannot contain constant functions or else you'd have the zero function in $S'$ and $S'$ automatically becomes linearly dependent.

So suppose otherwise. You know that you can write
$$f_i(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f_i'(t)dt,\;\;\text{ for all }x\in[a,b].$$
Therefore if $a_1,\ldots, a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ are scalars and $$a_1f_1'(t)+a_2f_2'(t)+\cdots+a_nf_n'(t)=0,\;\; \text{ for all } t\in[a,b]$$
then integrating the above equation yields
$$\int_a^x a_1f_1'(t)+a_2f_2'(t)+\cdots+a_nf_n'(t)dt=0\;\;\text{ for all }x\in [a,b].$$
so that
$$a_1f_1(x)+\cdots+a_nf_n(x)=0,\;\;\text{ for all }x\in[a,b]. $$
But the set $S$ is linearly independent and therefore $a_1,\ldots a_n$ are all zero. This implies that $S'$ is also linearly independent.

Comment: Just a clarification to make sure. When you say S can't contain constant functions, you mean this can't happen if we use this "method", right? I mean, we can have constant functions which are linearly independent (ie the example provided, {$sinx, cosx, 1$}), but then we couldn't use this way to find it out? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes indeed it means you cannot use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good. But there is a simpler solution. Suppose that

$$a \sin x+b\cos x+c=0$$

for all $x$.

With $x=0$ we get

(1) $b+c=0.$

With $x=\pi/2$ we get

(2) $a+c=0.$

With $x=\pi$ we get

(3) $-b+c=0.$

From (1),(2),(3) it is easy to see that $a=b=c=0.$

Comment: I thought about that. The problem that came to mind was that I was using "particular values" of x to prove for all equations, and I wasn't sure of this being right. Now that I know, I think Wronskian would've helped a lot in this (it is just -1), but has not been proved at class so I can't use it. Thank you.